# Vim: Substitute based on another match in the line

Tags: text-processing, vim, regular-expression

I have rather large files in which I need to substitute `NX` for `N1` but only if the line already contains `NX` as a pattern. So far I do it manually by first searching for occurrences of `NX` with:

```
/NX
```

and then using

```
'<,'>s/N1/NX
```

But the files are really large and long and the chances of me making a mistake during this manual procedure are very high. Is there a way to do this more efficiently in Vim?

Here is an example of what a line in one of the files might look like:

```
S22Tg    K1B12N1Tg    D1AE22K5    K2B12N1Tg    D1AE22K6    W01B12N1Tg    D1AE22TDNXW01    W02B12N1Tg    D1AE22TDNXW02    W03B12N1Tg
```

Note, that the lines are all very similar and only differ in terms of the numbers occurring after the letters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Vim, you could limit your substitution to the lines that contain `NX`:

```
:g/NX/s/N1/NX/
```

Preceding the substitution with `/NX/` makes Vim perform it only on the next line that contains `NX` (using [ranges](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/cmdline.txt.html#%3Arange)), and using [`:g`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/repeat.txt.html#%3Aglobal) makes it run on all lines that match `NX`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't necessarily need to open the file in vim to do this. You can do it on the command line 
`sed '/NX/s/N1/NX/g' <filename> >> <newfilename>` 
and then rename the `<newfilename>` to the original file.

Comment: Thank you. I eventually opted for the pure vim solution as this was the focus of the question!